# Do computer mice really feel different when used on a MacBook? Will using a mouse specialized for Macs feel any different?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bluetooth, mouse

I own a new MacBook Pro and I've been using it without a mouse since I brought it out of the box.

I tried to use the wireless mouse (not Bluetooth, connected to the laptop using a receiver plugged in a USB port) I used on my old laptop. However, it felt different. It was somehow slower. The cursor didn't move as fast as  the cursor moves in Windows.

Is it really like this?

I found out that Apple sells a Bluetooth mouse called "Magic Mouse" for their devices. Will using that feel any different?

Comment: Did you adjust the mouse pointer acceleration settings in System Preferences? In general, I've found no significant difference between OS X and Windows when using a generic, third-party mouse. However, a mouse that uses a proprietary wireless dongle (e.g. many Logitech models) will of course only be as good as its OS X drivers.

Comment: No wonder. It feels the same as Windows now. Thanks! It's a Logitech mouse. What do you mean with it only being as good as its OS X drivers? Oh, and is there any way to disable natural scrolling only when there is a mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's just a difference in the mouse pointer acceleration.

It can be adjusted in System Preferences > Mouse > Then adjust the tracking speed.

Thanks calum_b.